# How can two rows be written atomically when one row has a foreign key into the other?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, clojure

I have a transaction where we insert a row of table `foo` and then a row of table `bar`. This ensures we either write both rows or neither. The trouble with this is `bar` has a foreign key into `foo`. Because we don't know the `id` of `foo` at the time of the `bar` insert, this fails the foreign key constraint.

Previously I've used tools like SQLAlchemy, when writing Python backends, that include the capability of flushing a session before the transaction is committed--this allows the user to derive the `id` of `foo` and pass it along to the `INSERT` into `bar` before actually writing anything.

My question is, in the context of JDBC and its Clojure wrapper, how can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previously I was attempting to use `(jdbc/query db-spec ["select id from foo where name='my_foo'"])` within the transaction to derive the dependent `foo` row ID. This was returning `nil` and so it seemed like the obvious method didn't work. However it turned out I was using `db-spec` and not the transaction connection, which if you use `jdbc/with-db-transaction` is bound in the vector.

For example:

```
(jdbc/with-db-transaction [t-conn db-spec]
  (jdbc/insert! t-conn :foo {:name "my_foo"})
  (jdbc/query t-conn ["select id from foo where name='my_foo'"]))
```

The `query` in the above form will yield the correct row ID.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert values into both tables in one query, e.g.:

```
create table foo (
    foo_id serial primary key, 
    name text);

create table bar (
    bar_id serial primary key, 
    foo_id int references foo, 
    name text);

with insert_into_foo as (
    insert into foo (name) 
    values ('some foo')
    returning foo_id
    )
insert into bar (foo_id, name)
select foo_id, 'some bar'
from insert_into_foo;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is part of what [`DEFERRABLE` foreign key constraints](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html) are for.

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
    DROP CONSTRAINT the_fk_name;

ALTER TABLE
    ADD CONSTRAINT the_fk_name 
      FOREIGN KEY (thecol) REFERENCES othertable(othercol)
      DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE;
```

then

```
BEGIN;

SET CONSTRAINTS DEFERRED;

INSERT thetable ...;

INSERT INTO othertable ...;

-- optional, but if you do this you get any errors BEFORE commit
SET CONSTRAINTS IMMEDIATE;

COMMIT;
```

I suggest using `initially immediate` and `set constraints` so that the rest of the time you don't create queued triggers. It's better for performance and memory use, plus it won't confuse apps that don't understand and expect deferred cosntraints.

If your framework can't cope with this you can use `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED` instead.